# Docker Compose Bash Command Not Working In YAML but Works Inside Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Following is my docker compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis"
    volumes:
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - ./redis-volume:/data:rw
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    
  service1:
    build: .
    image: 'myregistry.azurecr.io/myapp:latest'
    ports:
      - '5500:80'
    volumes:
      - ./appsettings.json:/app/appsettings.json
    command: bash -c 'for file in /app/ClientApp/dist/myapp/main*.js; do sed -i "s|original-text|replaced-text|" $$file; done'
```

As you can see there is a bash command to replace certain string in some js files. This command is not take effect when I do `docker-compose up`. There is no error as well. However it works fine if I CLI into the running container and execute the same command (except that off course, I use $file instead of $$file as there is nothing to escape here).

```
for file in /app/ClientApp/dist/myapp/main*.js; do sed -i "s|original-text|replaced-text|" $file; done
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Maybe this is not the issue, but you don't need the for loop, sed -i "s|original-text|replaced-text|" /app/ClientApp/dist/myapp/main*.js

Comment: Just tried this but not working.

Comment: What's in the Dockerfile; does it have an `ENTRYPOINT`?  Or, does that command execute, and the main container command having executed, the container exits immediately?

Comment: Following is my entry point `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyWeb.dll"]`

Comment: @DavidMaze - Good point. It directed me towards the solution. I now used `entrypoint` in docker compose yaml file instead of `command` and provided the command that I had in my dockerfile. Its working fine now. In short, this is how it looks now `bash -c 'for file in /app/ClientApp/dist/myapp/main*.js; do sed -i "s|original-text|replaced-text|" $$file; done; dotnet MyWeb.dll'`. You can probably post this as an answer. I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention in a comment that your Dockerfile sets

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyWeb.dll"]
```

This is [combined](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) with the `command:` from the `docker-compose.yml` file to form a single command to execute; the `bash -c ...` instruction just gets passed as additional parameters to your .Net application.

If you want to keep this overall approach, the simplest workaround is to override `entrypoint:` in your `docker-compose.yml` file, and make sure to invoke the original command at the end of it:

```yaml
entrypoint: sh -c 'for file in ...; do sed ...; done; dotnet MyWeb.dll'
```

A better approach could be to use both an entrypoint part and a command part.  A useful pattern here is to write a shell script that does the first-time setup, then launches the main container process given as command-line parameters.  This wrapper itself is your `ENTRYPOINT` and the command (your `dotnet MyWeb.dll`) becomes `CMD`.

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh .
# RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh   # if it's not already executable
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"] # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ["botnet", "MyWeb.dll"]
```

The script can do anything, but must end with `exec "$@"` to launch the main container process.  Since it is a totally normal shell script, you can run it outside of Docker, and you don't need to worry about YAML or `sh -c` or Compose escaping requirements.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Replace "original-text" with "replaced-text" in the affected files
for file in /app/ClientApp/dist/myapp/main*.js; do
  sed -i "s|original-text|replaced-text|" "$file"
done

# Now launch the main container process
exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this for redis

```
command:>
   sh -c "redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"
```

and for service1

```
command:>
   sh -c "for file in /app/ClientApp/dist/myapp/main*.js; do sed -i "s|original-text|replaced-text|" $$file; done"
```

Comment: For redis I don't have a problem. Its working fine. I already tried sh instead of bash but same issue.

Comment: Use build: context: . Here is the [link] (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/)

Comment: If I understand correctly, Context is where I can specify the path to my dockerfile. I am not sure how its relevant. Can you please provide some explanation on what you are suggesting?